Is asking to translate a short paragraph from English to Italian on topic here?
I want to see if I'm allowed to ask such a question in the main site?

Would you please translate the following paragraphs into Italian?  

a proposal for creating a remote sensing and photogrammeetry Q&A site    in StackExchange Network is in commitment phase now
All the instructions you need to know to be an effective committer to    the remote sensing and photogrammetry proposal in StackExchange
You can also have a look at the homepage and the "definition phase is    over!" page of this google site.
There I've summarized all the efforts from last year and also have    linked  to valuable tutorials which introduce the StackExchange
  network and make you more familiar with what I'm trying to do
Let's make a website for remote sensing and photogrammetry real. Let's all press "commit" button!   
Please share or like the post as much as possible. This will help it    be seen on more news feeds and it will likely be seen by more
  interested people.
Please share the page and invite others to like it in order to have more committers and probably a successful launch

I need them to post about this proposal in facebook pages that
  are related to the topic and promote it. Because as you know and as
  facebook suggests, posts in local languages receive more likes and
  more attention and so they might be seen by more people.
Hint: I just want those bulleted paragraphs in Italian not more.  


Related question (duplicate?): http://meta.italian.stackexchange.com/questions/12/are-questions-about-translation-requests-on-topic.

I don't think “translate this for me” is really on topic. It could be if a tentative translation (but not of the whole thing) was supplied and some points about it raised, such as “how could I better say this?” or “is this wording appropriate?”

thanks a lot. I had the same question is spanish se and they advised me to ask in the chat room. Am I allowed to do the same in the italian chat room, providing my explanations in the comments of the above link?

@sepideh: I agree wholeheartedly with egreg: basically, this sites is for people learning and researching Italian, not for people who requests services in Italian. Personally (but I am not an admin), I don't think the chat room is made for such requests either.

@DaG Well, chat rooms don't really have strict rules; if somebody pops in asking for help and somebody is willing to…

Of course I'll do some research through English to Italian dictionaries. But since I don't know any grammar I may have problems. Can't you just give me a hand and correct my mistakes? @DaG

@sepideh: Are you aware you are asking someone to do an unpaid work, albeit small?

On a different note, if the site you support is going to be in English, I don't see how it should be benefitted by people committing to it even if they don't understand English.

@DaG as I've told the links in the posts will be in English. I just wanted those posts in order to enable the people who are searching in their local language see those posts. I also said that I'll try to translate but since I'm not familiar with the grammar I may need help. For example see my post in the german chat room, but since I'm not aware how to make the present perfect tense in german I need help. I know that it is unpaid but SE is a Q&A site, too. And it's really hard for me to find a translator around because even

University of Tehran which is the biggest university in Iran doesn't have the Italian major

@sepideh: There are sites such as eLance and Proz, where I believe you can hire someone for a small, one-time job, but I don't know them well, nor am endorsing them.

I personally think that asking for unpaid work in chat is fine, provided it is clear that the asker is aware that he is basically asking for a relatively big favor and that he cannot complain if no one is willing to do it, or if the quality of the work is substandard.

@DenisNardin I just want something in Italian that almost means the same. I'm not looking for a high quality translation. As I said it's just for posting on social networks and I actually asked here this question in order to be sure that I won't be violating the rules by asking in the chat and to respect the experienced users

Basically, SE language sites do not like to do translations "from scratch."
A "translation" request is more "acceptable" if it includes a self-worked translation that shows that you have "tried."
But the best question of this sort is a self-worked translation, accompanied by a question (or two) about "grammar" or other points that you are not clear on in the language, within your translation attempt.
